# It's in your best interest to just leave me be

Tags: riddle

> Alone I protect and work when I shouldn't
> If I get mixed up with you I'll take a dive
> Squeeze in a sun god the wrong way and I will bug you
>
> Decapitate me if you have places to be
> Cut off my tail to hear the sounds of Jamaica
> Do both and I'll just be a bear

What am I?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are a

> scab.

It's in your best interest to just leave me be

> This is the best policy when you have one.

Alone I protect and work when I shouldn't

> A scab protects an injury while it heals. It also means a strikebreaker.

If I get mixed up with you I'll take a dive

> SCUBA.

Squeeze in a sun god the wrong way and I will bug you

> SC(AR)AB. It didn't need to be the wrong way: SCA(RA)B.

Decapitate me if you have places to be

> CAB.

Cut off my tail to hear the sounds of Jamaica

> SCA. (Usual spelling is SKA, but it is "to hear" ...)

Do both and I'll just be a bear

> Perhaps because of the identification of California (CA) with the grizzly bear.

Comment: "If I get mixed up with you I'll take a dive"..it's 'scuba'

Comment: you beat me. I was typing these up when I saw your answer come in... :P Nice work!

Comment: @manshu, I think I fixed that while you were typing your comment.

Comment: @kayzeroshort, sorry about that. (Is it considered rude around here to write a super-brief answer and then expand it? That's my usual practice with these, but it's kinda unfair to anyone who prefers to write a thorough answer first.)

Comment: You got all the clues correct, nice job! I honestly got the letters jumbled myself on the sun god line so yeah it didn't have to be backwards haha

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan no worries. you actually got your explanations out as well before I was finished, so you beat me twice. not sure about the quick answer etiquette either, i've been wondering about that. seems like all's fair in love and puzzles.